# Mock a private static field with JMockit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I have a class like the following;

```
class ClassA {
    private static File myDir;

    // myDir is created at some stage

    private static String findFile(final String fileName) {
       for (final String actualBackupFileName : myDir.list()) {
           if (actualBackupFileName.startsWith(removeExtensionFrom(backupFile))) {
               return actualBackupFileName;
            }
       }
    }
}
```

So, basically, I want to test this class by mocking out the File class so that when list() is called on it it returns a list of strings I define in my test class.

I've got the following but its not working at the minute, there's probably something obvious I'm doing wrong - I'm new to JMockit - any help is much appreciated!

```
@Mocked("list") File myDir;

@Test
  public void testClassA() {
    final String[] files = {"file1-bla.txt"};

    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
      new File(anyString).list(); 
      returns(files);
   }};

   String returnedFileName = Deencapsulation.invoke(ClassA.class, "findFile","file1.txt");

   // assert returnedFileName is equal to "file1-bla.txt"
  }
```

When running the above test I get a NullPointerException for the myDir field in ClassA - so it looks like its not getting mocked properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JMockit (or any other mocking tool) does not mock fields or variables, it mocks *types* (classes, interfaces, etc.) Where the instances of those types get stored inside the code under test is not relevant.

Example test for `ClassA`:

```
@Test
public void testClassA(@Mocked File myDir)
{
    new Expectations() {{ myDir.list(); result = "file1-bla.txt"; }};

    String returnedFileName = new ClassA().publicMethodThatCallsFindFile("file1.txt");

    assertEquals("file1-bla.txt", returnedFileName);
}
```

The above should work. Note that testing `private` methods directly (or accessing `private` fields) is considered bad practice, so I avoided it here. Also, it's best to avoid mocking the `File` class. Instead, test only your `public` methods, and use actual files instead of mocking the filesystem.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a million for your help Rogerio, this worked with one small change to your code - @Mocked File myDir had to be changed to @Mocked(methods={"list"}) File myDir to get it to work. I think this was maybe because the Deencapsualtion.invoke call maybe needs a real File object at some point, and mocking out all the methods seemed to be interfering with something. I'm a new user so can't vote you up - otherwise I would!

Comment: Great! Mocking `File` can indeed cause unexpected failures, at least in older versions of JMockit. I edited the answer with your changes.

Comment: @Rogério, the above way of creating a mock object (`myDir`) results in the reference being `null`, causing `myDir.list()` to fail with an `NPE`. Any idea why?

Comment: @mystarrocks Local mock fields are not supported anymore. The test was updated to use a mock parameter instead.

Comment: Ah I see. For some reason, I hate listing a bunch of mocks other than the maybe 3 at most, through `@Mocked` in the test method signature. I'd rather have preferred this way of using mocks.

Comment: Don't use actual files. Doing so engages a file *system* which adds race conditions and makes normally fast executing unit tests that execute in .01s into slow tests that execute into .5s.  (Now imagine having a thousand unit tests and you'll see that you'll have a slow feedback loop which will ruin the point of having fast executing unit tests to start with.)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the setField method from the Deencapsulation class.  Note example below:

```
Deencapsulation.setField(ClassA, "File", your_desired_value);
```

Comment: I found that `Deencapsulation` class doesn't have `setField()` anymore in **JMockit 1.45** (though 1.3.0 has).

Comment: Please do not use Deencapsulation directly. It is considered bad practice.

Comment: Is there a replacement for `Deencapsulation`? I need to set private static final field in `@Tested` object.

Answer (score -1):

try out this:

```
new Expectations {{
  invoke(File.class, "list", null, null);
  returns(files);
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the docs say invoke is for invoking a static method - list() on File is not static - doesn't seem to work.