# How to mock enum singleton with jmockit?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, singleton, jmockit

I have a dependency on an enum singleton class like

```
public enum SingletonObject {
  INSTANCE;
  
  SingletonObject() {
    // some annoying initialization
  }

  public callDB() {
    this.num = num;
  }

}
```

I am trying to test a class like

```
public class MyClass {
  public void doSomething() {
    // some code
    SingletonObject.INSTANCE.callDB();
  }
}
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32207813/10137647), I've tried simply testing the mock with the following code, but I seem to be running into problems with the enum calling its constructor

```
public class MyClassTest {
    @Mocked
    private SingletonObject singleton;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Deencapsulation.setField(SingletonObject.class, "INSTANCE", singleton);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertSame(singleton, SingletonObject.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

[Using an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346396/junit-tests-suppress-enum-constructor-by-mocking) seems somewhat promising, but I question whether that is the best way of going about this problem.

It looks like [PowerMockito is promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939023/how-to-mock-an-enum-singleton-class-using-mockito-powermock) as well, but I would like to save that as a last resort for various reasons.

So how can I mock this enum singleton without invoking its constructor?

Comment: Why - on earth - would one want to mock an `enum`?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I would like to verify that doSomething() is calling SingletonObject.INSTANCE.callDB(); without actually calling the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  This creates a partial-mock of 'MyClass' and a Mock SingletonObject, calls the (real) doSomething method of MyClass, and confirms that the (mock) callDB() method of SingletonObject is invoked by it precisely once.

```
@Test
public void testdoSomething(
    @Mocked final SingletonObject singleton)
{
    final MyClass clz = new MyClass();

    new Expectations(clz)
    {
        {
            SingletonObject.INSTANCE.callDB();
            times = 1;
        }
    };
    clz.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying this: java.lang.InternalError: class redefinition failed: invalid class
 at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)